# popup after contact form submit

Tags: emails

we want the "message sent" message that comes out after you submit the sitewide contact form to come out in a popup instead of in a div on the front page.  How can I achieve that?

I have googled everywhere and asked questions on drupal.org but no one has answered me.

Comment: To prevent the question being closed, please make sure you add in your own research effort, which is [**required**](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). This includes what steps you've taken to solve the problem, where those attempts failed, what errors you received, etc. A valid question will almost certainly be a lot longer than a single sentence describing what you want with "How can I achieve that?" at the end. This isn't a support forum, we are building a repository of high quality questions and answers - you need to spend some of your _own_ time before posting :)

Comment: oh, I thought this was a support forum, sorry

Comment: No apology necessary - it's an easy mistake to make, the layout is pretty similar to a forum. All we're expecting is that you've checked into the problem a good bit yourself before posting a question here. 9 times out of 10 you'll probably end up finding the answer yourself doing that. But for the times you don't this is the place to come (as long as the question is on-topic etc). Adding details of what you've tried just means we don't waste _your_ time by suggesting solutions that won't work, or _our_ time researching the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Better Messages](http://drupal.org/project/better_messages) module

> Better Messages is a very simple module that provides "Popup-like"
>   Drupal messages.
>
> Better Messages intends to let you control where and how you want to
>   see your Drupal messages! Combine different animations and override
>   better_messages.tpl.php to create your custom look.